# autocomplete, using both jquery and jquery UI version

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, overloading

I wonder if javascript can see the difference between the autocomplete() of jquery and the autocomplete() of jquery UI.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

I am using both versions and atm only the jquery one works. Is this due to syntax errors or because the functions can't be used together??

```
$("#auto").autocomplete($("#base_uri").val()+'ajax/search',{
            req_type: "POST",
            minChars: 1,
            delay: 200
            }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
                    $("#message-add").hide();
                    $("#auto").show();
                    $("#auto").focus();
                    $("#fake_to").append('<span id="'+data[1]+'">'+formatted+', '+'</span>');
                    $("#to").val($("#to").val()+ data[1] +', ');
                    $("#auto").val('');
            });

    $(function() {
            var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme"
            ];
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm *sure* using both of these will cause a conflict. Think about it--both take the `$.fn.autocomplete` function.

In other words, the one you include last will probably be the only one you can use.

I would recommend only using one at a time. In fact, the author of the non-jQueryUI one recommends that you use the jQueryUI version, as his version has been deprecated in favor for that one:

> Note (2010-06-23): This plugin is
>   deprecated and not developed anymore.
>   Its successor is part of jQuery UI,
>   and this migration guide explains how
>   to get from this plugin to the new
>   one.

There are a few nice features in the original that were not included in the jQueryUI one, but I think you can accomplish most of those features (and ways to do that have been asked as questions and answered here on StackOverflow).